# how to develop an application with hadoop support

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

I am very much new to hadoop and bigdata, Using horton work I got an idea about Pig,Hive and different type of analysis available with hadoop, but still i am unclear about the development stage
please give me some example about getting started to build an application with hadoop analysis suport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reach this [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

You will come to know about hadoop and it's installation.